# How to get all types of the inner structures of a nested type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a function bellow,

```
public void park( List<List< List< Integer>>> l){ System.out.println("park"); }
```

and when I tried to use Method.getParameters() + Parameter.getParameterizedType(), I got

```
 java.util.List< java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>>
```

But, I need to get the type of the inner side of the nested structure, say, **java.util.List< java.util.List<>>** and **Integer**
. When I get that, I use getAnnotationsByType to get all annotations of the inner structures.

I have thought to use the Parameter.getParameterizedType().toString() to parse the nested structure, but even if I do, I don't think the type string can be converted to Type.

Is it possible to get inner types of a nested structure? Anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this information through the `ParameterizedType` interface.

For example:

```
final Type parameterType = method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0]; // List<List<List<Integer>>>

if (parameterType instancof ParameterizedType) {
    final Type nextDown // List<List<Integer>>
        = ((ParameterizedType) parameterType).getActualTypeArguments();
}
```

And keep repeating until it is *not* a `ParameterizedType`.

Comment: BTW, because I need to use Parameter.getAnnotations. Are there good ways to convert Type here to Paramter?

Comment: Assuming you already know how to get the `Parameter`, then the `getParameterizedType()` method on the `Parameter` `Object` will return a `ParameterizedType` (if it is indeed a `ParameterizedType`).  So replacing the first line with `parameter.getParameterizedType();` should keep everything else the same.

Comment: You cannot go back the other way (since, given a `Type`, there's no guarantee there's a `Parameter` of that type, or that there's only one).

Comment: That's now another question, which I'm happy to answer, but would be better asked as another question (or by editing and adding to this one, although with an accepted answer that seems a little odd).  _But_ you'd effectively go down the same route as above, except using `method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes();` and `AnnotatedType#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments();`.

Comment: ok, I will ask another question. Thanks a lot for everything.