# How to new a nested structure dynamically?

Tags: java, reflection, nested

from [How to get all types of the inner structures of a nested type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495176/how-to-get-all-types-of-the-inner-structures-of-a-nested-type/60495337?noredirect=1#comment107027867_60495337), I know how to get the inner structures of a nested data type. But, how to new this type dynamically?

That is, I can create a nested data type with static code, say,

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>> obj=new LinkedList<>();
```

But, if the layers of the inner of the structure is variable, how to do that with a program?
Any ideas are appreciated.

Edit:
For example,

```
public void foo(LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>> inputParameter);  
//this line has to be changed because the number of inner LinkedList is variable.
LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>> list=new LinkedList<>();
//call    
foo(list);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve specifically here? Like why would you want to do this? Can you add clarifying details to your question, I am uncertain exactly what you are asking.

Comment: `new LinkedList<>();` is equivalent to `new LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>>()`

Comment: This is used as a test case input. You are right. I am just wondering if later this List<Object> is down casted to be LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>> obj as a parameter, will there be any errors? because its original structure is abstracted to be Object when it's initilialized.

Comment: Does the code pasted by you even compile? I doubt it.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking. Are you asking if one can safely do something like `foo = (List<Object>)obj;`, `bar = (LinkedList<LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>>)foo;`?

Comment: @VishalSharma Why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: @PiRocks It didn't compile for me.It was asking me to use jre1.7 or below. I am using java8 though.

Comment: @YuFang It seems to me you want to vary the type of a variable based on a run-time value? Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: Able to compile by using javaSE-1.7

Comment: Works for me on jdk10, and jdk8

Comment: @PiRocks Yes. More specifically,   how to initialize a type of a variable based on its run-time type?

Comment: What do you think the difference between `new LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>();`, and `new LinkedList<Object>();` is?

Comment: OK. I will try it.

Comment: @YuFang I think you might have misunderstood me. `new LinkedList<T>()`, creates the an empty linked list for any value of T. T is completely ignored at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to something like:

```
int n = 10;
LinkedList<linked list nested n times, aka 10 times> = new LinkedList<>();
n++;
LinkedList<linked list nested n times, aka 11 times> = new LinkedList<>();
```

Please don't do this. 
The only use case I can imagine for this is something like storing a tensor/ndarray, in which case there are number of libraries for this, and linked lists are probably not the best choice of data-structure here.

To initialize an empty `LinkedList` use `new LinkedList<>();` This will create an empty linked list. `LinkedList` does not know anything about the kind of elements it contains at runtime. In fact in certain older jdks classes did not have these kind of type parameters.